# redirecting to a child state doesn't work after adding url params in state definition

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my routeconfig file

```
.state('results',{
        redirectTo:'results.grid',
        url: '/results/{searchobject:json}',
        templateUrl: 'html/main_listing.html',
        params:{
            searchobject:null
        }
    })//Child state for results state
    .state('results.grid',{
        templateUrl: 'html/grid_listing.html'
    })
    //Child state for results state
    .state('results.list',{
        templateUrl: 'html/list_listing.html'
    })
```

This code is inside .run function

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
            if (to.redirectTo) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $state.go(to.redirectTo, {location: 'replace'})
            }
        });
```

$state.go("results",{searchobject:searchobject}) doesn't load grid state by default.

But it works perfectly fine when used without passing params in URL.

I don't understand why adding or removing url params makes any difference?